# Pass variable or expression into `aes`

Tags: r, ggplot2

I wrote the function to plot bar graph with factor variables. When I run my function,The error message was showed.
Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'dset' not found
How to revise my function? Thank you!

```
x1=factor(c("f","m","f","f","m","f","f","m","f","m"))
x2=factor(c("1","2","1","1","1","2","2","2","1","1"))
y1=c(10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19)
y2=c(10,12,12,13,14,15,15,17,18,19)
y3=c(10,12,12,14,14,15,15,17,18,19)
bbb<- data.frame(x1,x2,y1,y2,y3)


myfunc<-function(dataframe){
  library(ggplot2)
  dset<-dataframe
  for (i in 1:ncol(dset)){
    if (is.factor(dset[,i])==T){
      p3<-ggplot(data=dset, aes(x=dset[,i]))
      p3<-p3+geom_bar(colour='blue',fill='blue')
      print(p3)
    } 
  } 
}

myfunc(dataframe=bbb)
```

Comment: @ David Arenburg If changed, the graph was wrong.

Comment: Sorry, Change `aes(x=dset[,i])` to `aes_string(x=names(dset)[i])`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Converted to an answer, as it seems useful

`aes` is designed to evaluate unquoted column names within the scope of the provided dataset (`dset` in your case). `dset[, i]` is not a column name, rather a whole column which `aes` wasn't designed to deal with.

Fortunately, you can parse quoted column names to `aes_string`. Thus, using

```
aes_string(x = names(dset)[i])
```

instead of

```
aes(x = dset[, i])
```

Should solve your problem

Comment: @RichardScriven It's time to learn `ggplot` then :). You can rest assured it is working, as the OP already confirmed in comments

Comment: +1's all over the place. I trust that you wouldn't post it if it didn't work

Comment: How about expressions with function calls stored in a variable? Such as "exprVar = ensym(f(dset[ ,i])); aes(x = exprVar)"? How can I achieve this?